# c++11 std::atomic compare_exchange_weak and the stack container

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working my way through Anthony Williams Concurrency book for C++11.

I am a bit confused by the pop implementation of the lock free stack.

```
template<typename T>
class lock_free_stack
{
private:
struct node
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> data;
    node* next;
    node(T const& data_): data( std::make_shared<T>(data_)){}
};

std::atomic<node*> head;

public:

void push(T const& data)
{
    node* const new_node = new node(data);
    new_node->next = head.load();
    while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
}

std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
{
    node* old_head = head.load();
    while( old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));

            // Does This not return the data of the next node before the head if 
            // compare_exchange_weak returns true
    return old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
}
};
```

The line that is causing me confusion is the last two lines of the pop function.

```
    while( old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));
    return old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
```

Will the compare_exchange_weak function not change the old_head to the next node in the stack if it returns true? This will lead to the return statement returning data from the next node and not the old head at the top of the stack when old_head is not a nullptr.

Have I interpreted this incorrectly?

Comment: Has this sample got the ABA problem and also potentially reading undefined memory (old_head->next)?

Comment: @MikeVine it is assumed there is a head node defined. push has been called before pop. The idea of pop would be then to return the top node, I cannot see this happening when this is the case as it changes the old head to the next node when compare_exchange_weak == true

Comment: If theres only one reader then this would work. If however there's 2 readers or more then it fails. Is this class designed to be used with only 1 reader? If not I'll post an example of how it can fail.

Comment: it is designed for n threads. Well that's what the book intends. The container design is flawed as this was only intend to show the basics and not a complete lock free container design. If you can show me when it fails that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from my comment, if compare_exchange_weak succeeded, it managed to update `head` from the value `old_head` to the value `old_head->next` and therefore old_head is no longer part of the list and so can be correctly returned.

Its only if it returns `false` that it modifies the value of `old_head`

EDIT: Showing issues with the above code.

Firstly, if 2 threads get into `pop` and both read `head` (via `head.load()`) and get the same value of `old_head`

Thread one gets swapped out (say)

Thread two carries on running, pops the head and returns to caller, and the caller then deletes the value which holds the node.

Thread one then gets resumed and tries to read `old_head->next` to even *call* compare_exchange_weak.

HOWEVER, old_head points to memory which has been deleted. Undefined behavoir, you're lucky if you segfault.

Secondly, this has the classic ABA problem. I wont bother to explain that as its well documented and understood. Search for it.

Comment: yes exactly. and the return value if old_head is true will not be the original top node?

Comment: But the behavior you describe *is* the ABA problem.

Comment: @SChepurin No its not, the ABA problem is when something is popped from the stack and reinserted and the stalled thread then *succeeds* in popping it but sets up the next pointer to invalid. Its a subtle but real difference. The ABA problem can be solved by having an additional counter next to the ->next field and a 64bit CAS [assuming a 32 bit architecture]. The problem I describe cannot be solved using this - its more of a lifetime issue.

Comment: The behavior you describe then even don't have a name. Don't you think that it is better to be considered a "kind of" ABA problem leading to the undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1):

When `head.compare_exchange_weak` returns `false`, it modifies `old_head`.

When it returns `true`, it modifies `head` and does not modify `old_head`.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange and/or http://cpp0x.centaur.ath.cx/atomics.types.operations.req.html#p21